# PHPExcel - best practises for own files

Tags: php, class, oop, phpexcel

I am currently transforming an existing project from the deprecated (and old) Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer to PHPExcel and I am wodering how to best utilize it.

I read the docuemtation and the examples so I am aware of the structure of PHPExcel.

In the current project we used to create classes that extended the Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer class like this:

```
class mySpreadsheet extends Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer{
   private $some_variable;
   private $andanother;

   function __construct(){
   //Init goes here
}
```

All the examples I've seen use a procedural usage to generate the content. In general I do not have a problem in using procedural coding in PHP, but I prefer an object oriented approch to keep the code more readable and compact.

Any experiences? Advantages/Disadvantages? Cavenuts I missed out upon?

Comment: I would suggest sticking to an OOP format, but this sounds like it might be a better fit for programming.SO not SO itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recently I've written code for exporting yet simple reports by PHPExcel. 
It's an abstract class with abstract methods which refer for styles and data formatting. 
Different reports utilize extended classes from that abstract one. They consist only implementation for abstract methods.
In future we may have to customize reports by users wishes. It will be easy to do with such structure.
I avoided extending PHPExcel's classes and ready for PHPExcel 2.0 to come.

Comment: This looks very promising to me, it may be additonal work but will result in additional flexibility to react to future versions easily.

Answer (score 0):

So, I am working on a project with PHPExcel at the moment and realized, that I should have made it in an oop way. The code looks really messy but I'm too lazy to change it. The amount of code you use for creating an excel spreadsheet is really high in a procedural way. So I would definitely work with classes next time to improve the readability and maintainability. And, as far as I know, there shouldn't be any problems with OOP. It usually simplifies your work. ;)